# Shortcuts Quick Action to share document by email with fixed message

Tags: email, monterey, shortcuts-app

I found this easy to do with Automator, but couldn’t convert an Automator Quick Action or work out how to do this in Shortcuts.

How can I create a Quick Action in Shortcuts to share a file by email with a fixed message, message title and from a specific email address?

I’m on Monterey.

Comment: Why not making a shortcut open a "mailto:" link? I can answer this if you want